# Como abrir uma sala de chat no Stack Overflow?

Tags: suporte, chat

Alguém sabe como consigo abrir um chat com alguém aqui no Stack Overflow em Português? Para fazer para ela perguntas tipo essa que lhes faço agora?

Comment: Não tem um botão "criar sala" na visualização geral dos chats

Comment: Nada que o [Estouro de Pilha](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) não atenda?

Answer (score 7):

Para criar novas salas são necessários 100 pontos de reputação conforme a [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms) e 20 pontos para entrar em qualquer sala e enviar mensagens.

Answer (score 4):

[Aqui tem um link para o manual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms), onde se lê, e eu cito:

> ## Criar Salas De Bate-Papo
>
> Tipo De Privilégio: Privilégio De Comunicação
>   Concedido Com: 100 Pontos De Reputação
>
> ### Como faço para criar uma nova sala de bate-papo?
>
> Há um link para o bate-papo no cabeçalho de cada página. O link também é exibido no botão do Stack Exchange localizado no canto superior esquerdo de cada página. Clique em um desses links e depois clique no botão "criar uma nova sala", localizado na parte inferior da página Salas.

Comment: Só acho q o tfm tá meio defasado, não? rs..

Comment: @Math eu não sei, eu não frequento as salas de bate papo...

Comment: Me referia ao botão do stack exchange que mudou do topo esquero esquerdo para o direito